# How do I use Ant's DeployTask to deploy a Web application to Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, rest, deployment, ant, manager-app

```
$ ant deploy
Buildfile: /Users/simpatico/SOLR_HOME/build.xml

deploy:

BUILD FAILED
/Users/simpatico/SOLR_HOME/build.xml:531: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://localhost:8080/manager/deploy?path=%2Fsolr
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1436)
    at org.apache.catalina.ant.AbstractCatalinaTask.execute(AbstractCatalinaTask.java:228)

Total time: 2 seconds
```

In build.xml:

```
<!--http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/manager-howto.html#Executing_Manager_Commands_With_Ant-->
  <!-- Configure properties to access the Manager application -->
  <property name="url"      value="http://localhost:8080/manager"/>
  <property name="username" value="admin"/>
  <property name="password" value="admin"/>

  <!-- Configure the custom Ant tasks for the Manager application -->
  <taskdef name="deploy"    classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.DeployTask"/>

<!-- Configure the context path for this application -->
  <property name="path"     value="solr"/>

  <target name="deploy" description="Install web application"
          >
    <deploy url="${url}" username="${username}" password="${password}"
            path="${path}" war="file:${dist}/solr.war"/>
  </target>
```

Both a path of /solr and solr don't work.

```
<tomcat-users>
    <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
    <user password="admin" roles="manager-gui,manager-script,admin" username="admin"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

EDIT: now it fails to deploy becauase the app already exists at path /solr

> undeploy:  [undeploy] OK - Undeployed
>   application at context path /solr
>
> deploy:    [deploy] FAIL - Application
>   already exists at path /solr
>
> BUILD FAILED
>   /Users/simpatico/SOLR_HOME/build.xml:532:
>   FAIL - Application already exists at
>   path /solr

Comment: does the user admin/admin have the correct roles configured in tomcat-users.xml to acces the management interface?

Comment: @simpatico: 403 means "Forbidden", are you sure you provide correct credentials? BTW, what version of Tomcat is used (is it 5.5)?

Comment: @barti_ddu - tomcat 7. I've provided the credentials on both sides in the q (admin/admin)

Comment: @simpatico: afair, for tc7 deployment url looks like `http://host:port/manager/text/deploy?path=/foo`

Comment: for some reason SO won't show a part i've added to the question which shows the modified deploy and undeploy targets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check out the documentation page of the [Manager App](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Executing_Manager_Commands_With_Ant), you can see the main difference is the url of the script. The example uses (mind the `/text` part):

```
<property name="url"      value="http://localhost:8080/manager/text"/>
```

In a *nix environment you have to check what user runs the server, and if that user has the correct permissions to alter files under your web directory.

Comment: @vbence - you nailed it (I was looking at 5.5 that google gave). Now however it doesn't deploy becasue the app is already deployed, as shown in Q edit.

Comment: @simpatico just copy-paste the **undeploy** task from the documentation.

Comment: @vbence - that's what i did, and modified the deploy to depend on undeploy

Comment: @simpatico I guess you "deployed" your application by hand (not thru the Manager App). Try deleting it by hand and then making the initial deployment thru `ant`. After that you must be able to *undeploy* it.

Comment: @vbence - nope, undeployed by hand.. then ant deploy it works (since there's nothing to undeploy) but ant deploy again will give the error

Comment: @simpatico You can not deploy two times in a row. You have to undeploy to be able to deploy again.

Comment: @vbence - yes, but every deploy is preceeded by an undeploy, which even reports success.

Comment: @simpatico Interesting.. try separating them to different tasks.

Comment: @vbence - what I've found out is that ant undeploy deletes the app from webapps but then it reappears immediately..what might be going on?

Comment: the issue is that I had under $CATALINA_HOME/conf/Catalina/localhost a solr.xml that deployed the app automatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
<target name="tomcatdeploy" description="Install web application"  >
    <deploy_tomcat url="${admin.url}" username="${admin.name}" password="${admin.password}" path="/${webapp}" war="file:${dropoff.warfile.dir}/${webapp}.war"/>
</target>

 <target name="check-context">
    <available file="${app.base.dir}/${webapp}.war" property="context.present"/>
</target>

<target name="undeploy" depends="check-context" if="context.present" description="Remove web application" >
   <undeploy_tomcat   url="${admin.url}" username="${admin.name}" password="${admin.password}" path="/${webapp}"/>
</target>
```

First call "undeploy" then "tomcatdeploy" ant tasks. You have to provide ${pamram} values as necessary. "undeploy" task will check if given war file exists in the webapps directory, if so it will do actual un-deploying.